# outlook add-in,build a relation between an email and the reply email

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto

Everyday,I need to hand more then 100 emails,and now I want dispatch these email to my partner,who can help me reply these email,but I want to detect which email is replied,and which is not.so I want to create a relation between email and the reply of this email,the relations are stored in our database,but I can't find relations between email and email's reply,I want you can help me.

Comment: Questions in StackOverflow should be related to programming. You might wanna try in www.superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Conversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862527.aspx) object from the Outlook object model which represents a conversation that includes one or more items stored in one or more folders and stores. A conversation represents one or more items in one or more folders and stores. If you move an item in a conversation to the Deleted Items folder and subsequently enumerate the conversation by using the GetChildren, GetRootItems, or GetTable method, the item will not be included in the returned object. See [How to: Get and Display Items in a Conversation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184625.aspx) for more information.